# vptr and buffer overflow issue

Tags: c++

I have an object of an inherited class type (say it's type B and it inherits from A), and I suspect it's vptr gets corrupted due to buffer overflow somewhere in the system. I think this is the case because in runtime when trying to access a public method of that object I SOMETIMES get "Access violation."

A. Any ideas? 
B. I get a pointer to object A as a parameter to the method where I try to access it. If indeed the vptr is corrupted can I verify this by trying to perform dynamic_cast on the A pointer to use it as B and hope it fails in case there's a problem with the vptr?

Thank you

Comment: I have a few questions:
1. Which language? 
2. Is your application multi-threaded, so the object passed to your method is being written to by another thread, while you try to access it?
3. Is it a case where your application is distributed on different machines, and this object was created after type casting a buffer received from the network?

Comment: You need to show some code that demonstrates what you're talking about.

Comment: @Ozair: It's almost certain to be C++ (which is why I retagged the question). I'm also almost certain that the problem the OP faces is simpler than the scenarios you listed. :-)

Comment: What did _valgrind_ tell you?

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry I forgot - This IS C++. Valgrind didn't say anything as I'm working on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad A: Try using [duma](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) or [electric-fence](http://perens.com/FreeSoftware/ElectricFence/) library for debugging buffer overruns.

Ad B: Yes, if the vptr is corrupted, dynamic_cast will fail on it.